# Solr JVM-Memory Spikes using List Manager Upload

Tags: solr, list-manager

`Sitecore 9.2`
`Solr 7.5`
`JVM-Memory 1024mb`

I have a `CM-CD environment` for production and I have noticed any time when uploading a CSV via `list manager`, JVM-Memory spikes to - and maintains a range of - 77%-90%, from 45%-60%. I have implemented a custom contact facet. I have noticed that the standalone servers have no issue with 512mb, but had to increase JVM-memory to 1024mb on CM. The list being uploaded has 1 row and still causes a spike. I am not seeing any error messages on Solr logs. I feel like increasing JVM-memory is a band-aid solution here as our standalone servers are running efficiently with 512mb.

How may I debug this issue efficiently? Would using the `List Manager API` be useful with `custom contact facets`?

Comment: Are you saying that you're running Solr on the same server as your CM instance?

Comment: Yes @MatthewFitzGerald-Chamberlain

Comment: Eek. Rolling your own Solr with default settings on the same server as your CM instance is going to be a bad time, especially if you're heavily leveraging xDB/lists/EXM. You should at least get it off the CM box with proper memory/GC settings, but look at just getting it hosted ie by SearchStax

Comment: We have had the same process for 4+ years with JVM-memory = 512mb. Should adding list and exm functionality make this much of a change? There has been millions of records and still no spikes or issues with Solr/within JVM-memory. Do you still recommend scaling out Solr?

Comment: To be clear, I would *never* recommend putting Solr on the CM instance with the default settings in any installation. But putting that aside, yes, the List Manager/EXM is going to put a large load on your indexing and will need to be addressed.

Answer (score 0):

When you upload 1 contact, it tells all the segments and MA plans to take note of the event. This causes a query against all contacts to see if anything has changed and if any contact needs to move.

I production, our JVM is at 3.6GB with 10GB xDB index size.

Comment: Is this specific to CM instances? In standalone versions, I don't see this behavior.

Comment: Should see it in both. Is there a number of contacts difference between the two environments? In prod we have 1 mil contacts.

Comment: My production has just over 1million+ contact records in dbo.xdb_shard0 and shard1.Contacts. I have resotred shard0 and shard 1 into a standalone and tried uploading a csv via list manager and minimal spikes (45-55%) were shown. This standalone has 512mb in JVM-memory.

Comment: Do you have the same segmented lists and MA plans in your standalone? You would need to bring Core/Master/Web/MA and Reference Data databases to copy those down also.

Comment: Will bring them down now. Just a note, we are not using MA at all.

Comment: No spikes in JVM-memory at all. Still fluctuating around  40%-50%